# Reading depth data from AVCapturePhoto's fileDataRepresentation

Tags: swift, avfoundation

Based on the [example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/additional_data_capture/capturing_depth_using_the_lidar_camera) from swift, I can combine image and depth data.

Using that format, I assume that I can save the image along with depth data as [Data class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephoto/2873919-filedatarepresentation).

After the data is saved, I can successfully read the image data using this snippet.
But I can't find an example to load the depth data.

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "filename", withExtension: "the_extension")!

let fileDataRepresentation = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
let uiImage = UIImage(data:fileDataRepresentation)
let depthData = AVDepthData(data: ???) // how can I load the data?
```

I have tried to ask Bard, but it just keep telling me to use a method that doesn't exist

```
let photo = AVCapturePhoto(fileDataRepresentation: fileDataRepresentation) // this doesn't exist
```